# create a sequence for rows with similar ids using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a datastructure similar to this

```html
+---------+---------+
|      id | value   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |   value |
        1 |   value |  
|       1 |   value |       
|       1 |   value |      
|       1 |   value |        
|       2 |   value |       
|       2 |   value |      
|       2 |   value |      
|       3 |   value |      
|       3 |   value |     
|       3 |   value |       
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

I am trying to update this table to look something like this

```html
+---------+---------+
|      id | value   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 | value 0 |
        1 | value 1 |  
|       1 | value 2 |       
|       1 | value 3 |      
|       1 | value 4 |        
|       2 | value 0 |       
|       2 | value 1 |      
|       2 | value 2 |      
|       3 | value 0 |      
|       3 | value 1 |     
|       3 | value 2 |       
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

To achieve this, i have written php script that looks like this

```html
$query = "select count(*) as count,id, value from foo group by id";
$sql=$con->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 while($row=$sql->fetch()){
  $id[] = $row['id'];
  $count[] = $row['count'];
  $value[] = $row['value']; 
  echo "<pre>";
 }
 $c=array_combine($id, $count);
 foreach ($c as $key=>$value){

            for($i=0;$i<=$value;$i++){
                $postid = $key;
                if($i==0){
                $multiple = "multiple";
                $newvalue= $value;
                }
                else{
                    $x=$i-1;
                    $multiple = "multiple_".$x;
                    echo $multiple . "<br>";
  $query2 = "update foo set value = :multiple";
  $sql2=$con->prepare($query2);
  $sql2->bindValue(':multiple', $multiple);
  $sql2->execute();
  
  }
   }
        }
```

The problem is that the code returns the following results

```html
+---------+---------+
|      id | value   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 | value_1 |
        1 | value_1 |  
|       1 | value_1 |       
|       1 | value_1 |      
|       1 | value_1 |        
|       2 | value_1 |       
|       2 | value_1 |      
|       2 | value_1 |      
|       3 | value_1 |      
|       3 | value_1 |     
|       3 | value_1 |       
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

What can i be possibly be doing wrong?

Thanks @Shadow

Your query runs fine but returns the following results

```html
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id   |           value                               |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|    1 |    multiple_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 |
|    1 |    multiple_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1 |
|    1 |    multiple_1_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2 |
|    1 |    multiple_1_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3 |
|    2 |    multiple_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 |
|    2 |    multiple_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1 |
|    2 |    multiple_1_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2 |
|    2 |    multiple_1_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3 |
|    3 |    multiple_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 |
|    3 |    multiple_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1 |
|    3 |    multiple_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is there a column in the table autoincrement?

Comment: Thanks @rad11. Yes there is a primary key with autoincrement

Comment: tell me name column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the update iterating and creating data in such a way:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM foo");
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$response = array();
foreach ($data as $dataIndex => $dataValue) {

    if (!isset($response[$dataValue["id"]]["count"])) {
        $response[$dataValue["id"]]["count"] = 0;
    } else {
        $response[$dataValue["id"]]["count"] ++;
    }

    $response[$dataValue["id"]]["values"][$dataValue["pid"]] = "value_" . $response[$dataValue["id"]]["count"];

    $sth = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE foo SET value = '{$response[$dataValue["id"]]["values"][$dataValue["pid"]]}' WHERE pid = {$dataValue["pid"]}");
    $sth->execute();
}
?>
```

But try to do an update using the least iteration not to create as many database queries , example:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM foo");
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$response = array();
$update = array();
foreach ($data as $dataIndex => $dataValue) {
    $response[$dataValue["id"]]["id"] = $dataValue["id"];

    if (!isset($response[$dataValue["id"]]["count"])) {
        $response[$dataValue["id"]]["count"] = 0;
    } else {
        $response[$dataValue["id"]]["count"] ++;
    }

    $response[$dataValue["id"]]["values"][$dataValue["pid"]] = "value_" . $response[$dataValue["id"]]["count"];
    $update[] = "UPDATE foo SET value = '{$response[$dataValue["id"]]["values"][$dataValue["pid"]]}' WHERE pid = {$dataValue["pid"]};";
}
$update = implode("",$update);
$sth = $pdo->prepare($update);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update query

```
$query2 = "update foo set value = :multiple";
```

does not contain any where criteria, each time you call this query it updates the value field's value in all records.

Honestly, I would not really involve php in this update, would do it purely in sql using user defined variables and multi-table join syntax in the update:

```
update foo inner join (select @i:=0, @previd:=-1) as a
set foo.value=concat(foo.value,'_',@i:=if(id=@previd,@i+1,0),if(@previd:=id,'',''))
```

The subquery in the inner join initialises @i and @previd user defined variables. The 3rd parameter of the concat function determines the value @i to be concatenated to the `value` field. The 4th parameter of concat sets the @previd variable and returns an empty string not to affect the overall concatenation. Unfortunately, I do not have access to MySQL to test the query, but it should be a good starting point anyway.

UPDATE

The OP claims in the updated question that the query I provided creates the below resultset:

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id   |           value                               |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|    1 |    multiple_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 |
|    1 |    multiple_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1 |
|    1 |    multiple_1_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2 |
|    1 |    multiple_1_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3 |
|    2 |    multiple_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 |
|    2 |    multiple_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1 |
|    2 |    multiple_1_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2_2 |
|    2 |    multiple_1_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3_3 |
|    3 |    multiple_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 |
|    3 |    multiple_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1 |
|    3 |    multiple_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Tested my solution in sqlfiddle. I had to remove the order by clause, otherwise the query produced the results in line with the requirements stated in the question. See [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e93f29/2) for details.

The results in the updated question are likely the result of running the query in a loop multiple times. In simple words: you just copy pasted the query into your code and did not remove the loop, even when I pointed out, that this may be the reason of the results you received.

Comment: Thank you @Shadow. Please see edited question for results returned by your suggested script which is quite crisp and sharp

Comment: You only get the above output, if you run my query in a loop from your php code. You only need to run it once.

Comment: brilliant stuff. but it still appends the 0(zero) i.e., value_0, value_0_1, value_0_2 etc. while the desired output is value_0, Value_1, Value_2 etc

Comment: @tomsawyer See updated answer, you must have run my query in a loop, instead of running it only once.